# Como mudar a URL de site.com.br/index.php para site.com.br/ através do .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Tenho a URL com o seguinte padrão:

> `https://dominio.com.br/index.php`

Eu tentei mudar de index.php para nada, dessa maneira:

> `https://dominio.com.br/`

Com a seguinte regra:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\/?$ index.php [NC,L]
# Outras Rules
```

Porque ela não mudou?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente testar esse código:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Caso não funcionar, significa que você não tem permissão para editar o htaccess. Ai tem que entrar em contato com o domínio do site ou entrar no cPanel.